# ¿Cómo puedo pasar este codigo a Typescript?

Tags: angular

Quiero pasar este codigo en Java, a Typescript, la verdad me ha costado mucho trabajo, ya que soy novato en esto de typescript.

Esta parte es la que más me ha costado trabajo

```
public Persona() {
        this("", 0, SEXO_DEF, 0, 0);
    }
```

Este es el codigo para que vean como está contruido

```
    private final static char SEXO_DEF = 'H';

    /**
     * El peso de la persona esta por debajo del peso ideal
     */
    public static final int INFRAPESO = -1;

    /**
     * El peso de la persona esta en su peso ideal
     */
    public static final int PESO_IDEAL = 0;

    /**
     * El peso de la persona esta por encima del peso ideal
     */
    public static final int SOBREPESO = 1;

    //Atributos
    /**
     * Nombre de la persona
     */
    private String nombre;

    /**
     * Edad de la persona
     */
    private int edad;

    /**
     * DNI de la persona, se genera al construir el objeto
     */
    private String DNI;

    /**
     * Sexo de la persona, H hombre M mujer
     */
    private char sexo;

    /**
     * Peso de la persona
     */
    private double peso;

    /**
     * Altura de la persona
     */
    private double altura;

    //Contructores
    /**
     * Constructor por defecto
     */
    public Persona() {
        this("", 0, SEXO_DEF, 0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor con 3 parametroe
     *
     * @param nombre de la persona
     * @param edad de la persona
     * @param sexo de la persona
     */
    public Persona(String nombre, int edad, char sexo) {
        this(nombre, edad, sexo, 0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor con 5 parametros
     *
     * @param nombre de la persona
     * @param edad de la persona
     * @param sexo de la persona
     * @param peso de la persona
     * @param altura de la persona
     */
    public Persona(String nombre, int edad, char sexo, double peso, double altura) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.altura = altura;
        generarDni();
        this.sexo = sexo;
        comprobarSexo();
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, añade lo que tengas ahora mismo hecho en Typescript, indicando qué problemas o dudas tienes. La pregunta ahora mismo parece una petición del tipo *Hacedme la tarea*, lo que no es algo que hagamos por aquí

Comment: Hay transpiladores entre diferentes lenguajes, p.e. para lo que necesitas: http://www.jsweet.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class Persona {
   private nombre: string;
   private DNI: string;
   private edad: number;
   private sexo: string;
   private peso: number;
   private altura: number;

   constructor(
       nombre: string = '',
       edad: number = 0,
       sexo: string = 'H',
       peso?: number,
       altura?: number
   ) {
       this.nombre = nombre;
       this.edad = edad;
       this.sexo = sexo;
       this.peso = peso;
       this.DNI = this.generarDni();
       this.altura = altura;
   }

   generarDni() {
       return 'Z7748048C'; // Aquí iría el código de genración del DNI
   }

   // Setters y getters over here .....
}
```

En el constructor por defecto no podrás hacer que valores opcionales como lo son la altura y el peso tengan un valor por defecto de base (ya que estos pueden estar o no dependiendo de como los crees). Para crear una persona solo tendrás que hacer lo siguiente:

```
const persona1 = new Persona() // {"", 0, H}
const persona2 = new Persona("", 0, "H", 0, 0);
const persona3 = new Persona("Anfony", 24, "H");
const persona4 = new Persona("X", 123, "H", 73.4, 1.80);
```

Comment: Podrías poner `private`delante de cada parámetro del constructor y te ahorrarías la declaración antes

Comment: @PabloLozano vale, muchas gracias, lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: @DarwinGonzalez podrías usar constructores abreviados que propone TypeScript para ahorrar líneas de código. Acá hay un ejemplo https://gustavodohara.com/blogangular/creando-clases-con-constructores-en-typescript/